# The Foci Of An Ellipse

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

In Wikipedia the definition of and ellipse is the following.

> An ellipse is a set of points, such that for any point $P$ of the set,
>   the sum of the distances $|PF_{1}|, |PF_{2}|$ to two fixed
>   points $F_{1},F_{2}$, the foci, is constant, usually denoted by $2 a$.

Then the following image is given:

[image]

Why is the the sum of the distances $|PF_{1}|$ and $|PF_{2}|$ is $2a$?

Comment: It's the definition of the ellipse.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I can see that $|PF_{1}|^2+|PF_{2}|^2=|F_2-F-1|^2$, But vector-wise I can not see how is it equal to $2a$

Comment: See my post. I hope it will help.

Comment: Try to imagine $P$ at one of the vertices on the $x-$axis $F_1V_1+F_2V1=2a$ and all the other points must satisfy this property. By definition. Even if there is a link between the ellipse defined as a conic section and the locus we are talking of.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dandelin_spheres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$PF_1+PF_2=V_1F_1+V_1F_2=V_2F_2+V_1F_2=2a$$

Comment: How do you get to this equation?

Comment: @gbox Because by definition of ellipse $PF_1+PF_2=constant$ for all $P$ on the ellipse. Now, Let $P\equiv V_1$ and the rest you saw.

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of an ellipse - the shape that you get when the sum of lengths is constant. Now, if your question is why this sum of lengths is exactly equal to the length major axis, then you can just take note that the maximum extent will be achieved when both lines are in the same direction, which gives Michael Rozenburg's answer.